# focus lost after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, focus

I have a listview which contains an edittext in each row. When I add text in the last row of the listview, I want to add an empty row to the listview. So I change my list and call notifyDataSetChanged(). Unluckily the focus goes to a place outside of listview. How can I keep the focus in my current edit_text? I have tried edit_text.requestFocus() - but it did not work.

Code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.design_listview, parent, false);

    EditText edit_text=(EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_edittext);

    edit_text.setText(values.get(position).text);

    edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int j, int k) { }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int j, int k) { }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            values.get(position).text=editable.toString();

            if(position == values.size()-1 && editable.toString().length() > 0) {
                listaddItem();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                // How to keep the focus? edit_text.requestFocus(); did not help
            }
        }
        // ..
    return rowView;
    }
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe edit_text.setSelection(0); works?